# I dn't know how to fixe this error : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: node.js

I work with nodeJS and express.
I don't know how to fix this error, please help :)
In the server :

```
 app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
        userInfos = bll.retrieveDataUser(); // [userEmail, userPassword, userName, userId]
        res.send({
            userEmail: userInfos[0],
            userPassword: userInfos[1],
            username: userInfos[2],
            uId: userInfos[3]
        });
```

In the client :

```
fetch(`/home`).then((res) => {
        res.json().then((data) => {
            if (data.error) {
                throw error
            } else {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
    })
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to return json then you should use express's `res.json` method.

```js
app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
    userInfos = bll.retrieveDataUser(); // [userEmail, userPassword, userName, userId]
    res.json({
        userEmail: userInfos[0],
        userPassword: userInfos[1],
        username: userInfos[2],
        uId: userInfos[3]
    });
)};
```

and your fetch request syntax is also invalid.

```js
    fetch(`/home`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        if (data.error) {
            throw error
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
```

Comment: if you find the answer useful make sure to accept answer to your question.

Comment: I'ts work thank you, in the terminal of visual Studio i have the data  ! but in the console of the browser i have still the error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". Do you know why ?

Comment: make sure you are fetching from correct url.. if your front end is on different port and backend is on different port make sure to add proxy to front end for fetch requests.